# How To Stop One (1) Character CAPTCHA Answer From Being Successful Even If Trailed by Other Characters

Tags: php, regex

...is how I think I should phrase the question atleast. It's a tricky one. I've noticed that my CAPTCHA (who's answer happens to be one letter, e.g. "A"), will consider any Answer to be correct as long as the first letter is "A". So if someone were to type Apple, it would accept that as a correct answer. Is there a way to remedy this? Current code:

```
}
if (!preg_match("/A/", $captcha))
{
show_error("Incorrect CAPTCHA Answer");
}
```

Thank you

Entire .php code:

```
<?php
$myemail = "email@domain.com";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Text <domain.com>';
$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail Address not valid");
}
if (!preg_match("/A/", $captcha))
{
show_error("Incorrect CAPTCHA Answer");
}
$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $from);

header('Location: page.html');
exit();

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

CAPTCHA aspect of HTML code:

```
<p class="c-font-lowercase">The first letter in the alphabet is?
<input type="text" placeholder="CAPTCHA Answer" name="captcha" class=""/>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of anchoring a regex?

Comment: Also, this question can probably be generalized -- I don't see anything actually specific to CAPTCHA here, so writing the question to ask about regular expressions rather than CAPTCHAs would make that question more useful to others. (One of the core goals of SO is to generate a knowledge base with both questions and their answers helpful to as many people as possible).

Comment: `/^A/` is a regex anchored to the beginning -- only accepting things that start with `A`, and `/A$/` is anchored to the end -- only matching things that end with A. `/^A$/` is anchored in both places, only accepting things where `A` is the only character between the start and the end. It's possible that `preg_match()` is implicitly anchored at the beginning, and so that the anchor at the end is the only one you need to make explicit -- I don't know php (this is part of why tagging your question with the language you're working in is so important), so couldn't say.

Comment: BTW, the reason I'm not so sure about the question title is that people use regexes for lots of things, not just CAPTCHA; we wouldn't want 20 different versions of the same question and answer, with one talking about CAPTCHA, another talking about grepping, another talking about file selection, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `preg_match()` at all here:

```
if ($captcha != "A") {
  show_error("Incorrect CAPTCHA Answer");
}
```

However, if you *did* want to use it, be sure to anchor your regex:

```
if (!preg_match("/^A$/", $captcha)) {
  show_error("Incorrect CAPTCHA Answer");
}
```